# prefix of folders in linux to make them stay on first position

Tags: linux, directory, kde-plasma, ubuntu, alphabetical-sort

System: KUBUNTU 14.4, KDE 3, Language: DE/Western European

I have several folders inside a parent folder. Those folders have names starting with chars or numbers.

```
/0123_foo
/3321__blubb
/bam
```

I want to sort out outdated folders and move them into a new folder (/archive) which also lays inside the parent folder. I want this new archive folder to be listed in alphabetical order as first folder.

- What prefix can I use, to "pin" my folder to the start of the list.
- What is the sorting algorithm in KDE when I use "sort by file/folder names"?

I tried "_archive" but underscore will be sorted after numbers. Even with # (#archive) that has a lower ASCII value than numbers have, numbers will rank first.

Comment: Here's an ASCII chart: http://www.asciitable.com/ where you can see which characters go before numbers. They're all punctuation characters.

Comment: Doesn't work like that. For example: if I name the folder "#archive" it will be sorted after "0123_foo". So Its back to the sorting algorithm of KDE.

Comment: This may be a locale issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work for you. Rename `archive` to `#archive` and use

```
ls -1 | sort -g
```

to list all the files in a sorted manner according to ASCII value or

```
ls -v -r
```

it will put `#archive` at the end then reverse the entire list